# Global variable fails to compile, yet its local equivalent works

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, global-variables, local-variables

The following code (using a the global var 'locationManager') gives me a compiler error:

```
var userlocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
var boundingRegion:MKCoordinateRegion?
var mapViewController:MapViewController?

class MainViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    }
}
```

Here's the compiler error:
[image]

Yet, using a *local* variable, the following compiles: 
[image]

Why would a global variable fail to compile, but its local equivalent works?